# Почему POST запрос не хочет передаваться?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Я попробовал несколько библиотек, но ни одна не дала результатов,
пробую вот это:

```
    var needle = require('needle');

needle.post('https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.get', {access_token: '123467',
          v : '5.95',
          count: 1},
    function(err, resp, body){
        console.log(body);
});
```

Но ответ примерно один:

> error_msg: 'User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).',

Comment: Ошибка говорящая. "Ошибка авторизации пользователя: недопустимый access_token (4).". Документация ВК гласит, что это "Неверная подпись".

Comment: Технически пост-запрос отлично передался, но вк не нравится то что в нем написано. Потому что в документации сказано, что токен должен быть в query-параметрах. И вам про это уже написали в тостере, какой смысл был задавать этот же вопрос тут?

Comment: надеясь получить ответ подробнее